# Should I set CURLOPT_SSLKEY if CURLOPT_SSLCERT is set to a file with both a certificate and a private key?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, certificate, ssl-certificate

The server gave me a client certificate `customer.pem` which I should use. If I open it in a text editor it contains both a client certificate and a client key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
here is private key
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
here is certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But [according to PHP curl doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) there are two separated options for setting client certificate and private client key:

```
CURLOPT_SSLCERT The name of a file containing a PEM formatted certificate;
CURLOPT_SSLKEY  The name of a file containing a private SSL key;
```

Having `customer.pem` file with both a certificate and private key - can I set just `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` option? Will CURL automatically read a client key and use it correctly? Like the following:

```
$curl_opt = array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $cert_dir . 'customer.pem',
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => $cert_dir . 'ca.crt',
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => $extra_settings['certificate_password'],
);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: The server knows the client private key? This is a security problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` points out a PEM file that contains both the cert and the key, then you don't need to use/set `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` at all.